# PHP function array parameter by reference

Tags: php, arrays, function, reference

Why this code not works as I expected?
Inside the Test(&$array) function I would set the ref parameter to the global $array1 but this didn't works.

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();

function Test(&$array)
{
    global    $array1;
    $array = &$array1;

    $array['inside'] = 'inside';

}
```

//SET BY THE FUNCTION:

```
Test($array2); 
$array2['test1'] = 'test1';

var_dump($array1); //array('inside' => 'inside') ** WHERE IS THE 'test1'  key? **
var_dump($array2); //array('test1' => 'test1')   ** WHERE IS THE 'inside' key? **
```

//SET WITHOUT THE FUNCTION:

```
$array2 = &$array1;
$array2['test2'] = 'test2';

var_dump($array1); //array('inside' => 'inside', 'test2' => 'test2') ** FINE **
var_dump($array2); //array('inside' => 'inside', 'test2' => 'test2') ** FINE **
```

**EDIT:**

It's quite clear that if I changed $array to point to $array1 then $array1 will have the 'inside' => 'inside' value ***outside*** the function. What not clear that if I set $array2['test1'] = 'test1' **why not change this $array1 also**? Its 'linked' before inside the function!

Comment: Ever heard of return values?

Comment: @kingcrunch This is clearly a simplified test case, so criticising an unknown use case seems rather unhelpful.

Comment: @IMSoP OK, sorry :) But to be honest: I've never seen a useful use-case for in-out-params for years now and I fear they simply don't exists (anymore). But I've seen the pass-by-reference for micro-optimizations (beside: it doesn't optimize anything, because of copy-on-write) and then the same developers were confused, because the array "magically" changed, because some others uses array, like one uses array, that were passed as parameter :) What I want to say: No real use-cases, but many "wtf"-momemts are waiting.

Comment: @KingCrunch: The real function should return boolean value while set up multiple parameter values by reference. This is a design pattern from my .NET C# solutions. I just like to implement it by php.

Comment: @ggabor This "return values as status parameter" is a bad habit. When your method fails, use exceptions, and when it succeeds, .. well don't throw an exception ;) and simply go on. Thats the reason why Exceptions exists: Inform you (and give you the opportunity to react on) exceptional situations. To be fair: Maybe in other languages it is a more adopted pattern, but at least not in the languages I know :) (I'm not so familar with the C-family)

Comment: @KingCrunch: I think its better to avoid exception if it were possible. Exceptions are need much resources and slows down entire process. Clear and smart algorythms never needs to throw exceptions. On the caller side I need only 1 line code instead of the complete exception handler logic. Some cases I need to use them but if I could I avoid to use them.

Comment: @ggabor "Much resources", how much? ;) Can you tell me, or did you just heard it? Of course they took resources, but in best (and most) cases they don't appear. Also even for you: Never let performance concerns decide over your application design. "Clear and smart algorithms never needs to throw exceptions" is simply wrong: If I have "save()" and it cannot save something, it is an exceptional state. And let LOCs decide about your application design seems to be even worse.

Comment: Maybe I have a bad habit but from my C# experience where I worked on a very large project with millions of records processing I measured that exception handling takes 5-6 seconds more for a simple query - even if none of them raised! I successfully tuned up the performance simple delete all unnecessary try - catch blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my understanding of references in PHP, and why that code doesn't do what you expect (somebody please jump on me if I get it wrong, I frequently do with references! Also, I'm sure there are better terms than what I'm calling "identifier" and "value"; I just wanted to avoid using "variable" for either concept.)

- There are a bunch of variable identifiers (the way you get at the data), and a bunch of variable values (where the data actually is)
- For a normal variable, there is just one identifier pointing at one value. e.g. `$foo` refers to a specific value - a bucket somewhere in PHP's internals that can hold a number, a string, etc
- Every time you use the normal assignment operator, e.g. `$foo = 42`, PHP looks for the value being pointed at and updates it - so the identifier `$foo` hasn't changed, but the value it points at has.
- When you assign a reference, e.g. `$bar =& $foo`, you are actually telling PHP to change the identifier itself. So now `$bar` and `$foo` are two different identifiers pointing at the same value. `$foo = -1` and `$bar = -2` will both write to this value, and whichever name you give it, you're referring to that value.
- So far, so good. But what if I now write `$foo =& $bob`? Since I'm changing the *identifier*, not the *value*, `$foo` starts pointing at the same value as `$bob`, but `$bar` stays where it was. So now, changing `$foo` won't make any difference to `$bar` any more.
- A similar thing happens when you pass in a parameter by reference to a function. So in the example in the question, the line `Test($array2)` still creates a new *identifier* inside the function called `$array`, but it points it at the same *value* as `$array2`. However, inside the function is the line `$array = &$array1` which takes that new identifier (`$array`) and points it at the same value as `$array1`. The old value, which `$array2` still points at, hasn't changed.
- There are other situations that act like this as well. For instance, the `global` and `static` keywords create an extra identifier pointing at an existing value. If you write `function foo() { global $foo;  $bar = 2; $foo =& $bar; }`, only the function's local identifier called `$foo` is updated to point at `$bar`'s value; the global identifier (which happens to also be called `$foo`, when you're in global scope) still points at its original value.

The reference system for ordinary values in PHP always includes *exactly one level of indirection* - you cannot create a pointer to a pointer to a pointer in the way that you could in C, for instance.

The only tricky case is objects, which as in many languages have an extra level of indirection all of their own - whereas `$foo = 42; $bar = $foo;` copies the data representing `42` from `$foo`'s value to `$bar`'s, `$foo = new stdClass; $bar = $foo` copies an *object pointer*. So although `$foo` and `$bar` still have separate *values*, and an assignment like `$foo = 42` won't have any effect on `$bar`, `$foo->a = 1;` and `$bar->a = 1` will both end up changing the same object.

Comment: Yep, this sounds right.  That's what I was trying to explain :-P

Comment: @RocketHazmat Could probably do with summarising the summary, though  - I'm not very good at being succinct... ;)

Answer (score 5):

When you do `$array = &$array1;` inside your function, you are changing the value of the local variable `$array`.

It used to have a reference to `$array2`, but now it contains a reference to `$array1`.  So when you modify `$array`, you're modifying `$array1`.

Comment: It always ties my head in knots working out what exactly `=&` will do, because you have to distinguish between the variable as a label and the variable as a container for some value.

Comment: @IMSoP: The `&` means "reference", so the `=&` means that the variable holds a "link" to another variable.

Comment: So it means that I cannot modify any parameter value outside the function even if it was passed by reference. Every function parameters are read-only even if passed by reference?

Comment: @ggabor: The problem is that you *changed* where the reference is pointing to.  `$array` used to point to `$array2`, but you changed it to point to `$array1` instead, so that's the array that got modified.  If you didn't have the `$array = &$array1;` line, then `$array['inside'] = 'inside';` would've modified `$array2`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That is exactly the mistake I (and I'm sure others) make: it is not a reference _to another variable_, both variables are references to the same value. Use `=&` again, on either variable, and they will be unlinked.